# ¿Cómo reemplazar un "path" por otro en una columna?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo la necesidad de actualizar unas rutas en una tabla de SQL mediante un `query`; la tabla se llama `documentos`, esta generada mas o menos de esta forma:

```
id | ruta | nombre
1 | c:\documentos\documento1.pdf | nombredeldocumento1
2 | c:\documentos\documento2.pdf | nombredeldocumento2
3 | c:\documentos\documento3.pdf | nombredeldocumento3
4 | c:\documentos\documento4.pdf | nombredeldocumento4
5 | c:\documentos\documento5.pdf | nombredeldocumento5
```

es necesario que ahora las rutas esten en: `d:\pdf\docs\` y que mantengan la ultima parte que seria `documento1.pdf` por lo tengo deberá quedar `d:\pdf\docs\documento1.pdf`.

La tabla tiene mas de quincemil registros por lo tanto hacerlo manualmente será una tarea terrible, alguien sabe como hacerlo vía SQL para actualizar esa parte del string con un substring o algo así?

Comment: Hola César, bienvenido a [es.so]. Como tal, el funcionamiento del sitio se basa en preguntas y respuestas concisas, además el esfuerzo por parte de la persona que pregunta es bastante aceptado, es decir, ya planteaste tu problema, ahora requerimos ver cuáles son las opciones que has intentado, algún *script* sería de ayuda para guiarte y ayudarte a solucionar tu problema. De igual forma te recomiendo tomar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así como revisar el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: te recomiendo que hagas un backup antes de meterle mano al SQL, sólo por si se te olvida el where y te cargas la tabla :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función SUBSTRING para obtener la última parte de la cadena.

Con esta consulta puedes comprobar que te devolvería correctamente los datos

```
SELECT 'd:\pdf\docs\' + SUBSTRING(Ruta, LEN('C:\Documentos\') + 1, LEN(Ruta))
    FROM documentos
```

Mientras que esta otra los modifica:

```
UPDATE documentos
   SET Ruta = 'd:\pdf\docs\' + SUBSTRING(Ruta, LEN('C:\Documentos\') + 1, LEN(Ruta))
```

Como te decían en un comentario anterior, hazte una copia de la tabla antes de modificar todos los registros.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma para quedarse con el nombre del archivo, al menos para mi gusto, es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Path   VARCHAR(255)
SELECT  @Path   = 'c:\documentos\documento5.pdf'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@Path)), LEN(@Path) )
```

Es un ejemplo, entiendo que después podrás adaptarlo a tu necesidad, básicamente se recorta a partir del primer '\' contando de atrás para adelante.